# Connection to Oracle in Reporting Services won't work after sp3 and cu1

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ora-12705

Last night I installed sp3 and cu1 on a 64 bit SQL 2005 failover cluster.

Everything went well.  Reporting services is installed on the primary node.

It now cannot connect to Oracle.  The initial errors seemed to be related to this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;en-us;870668

I granted network service access, but that didn't change anything.  I then made it like development (which is working fine, unfortunately), which meant adding authenticated users to the bin and admin\network folders.

This gave us a new error.

ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

Most posts on the web say this should happen in sqlplus as well.  It does not.

We have Oracle 10g and 9 drivers installed on this server.
The 9 drivers are 32 bit that SSIS is using.
It seems that reporting services is using the 10 drivers.

When I added security settings to the oracle folders as directed in the link above, I did it on the 9 drivers first and we got errors in rs saying that it could not use 32 bit drivers.  When I added the security settings on the 64 bit and removed 32 we started getting the NLS errors.

Thanks for any help!
Posting this to both SO and SF- I'd love to hear some ideas before we call MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several answers such as this:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12705_resolution.htm

Decided to rename the registry key and it worked.